# PhpMyAdmin: UploadDir & SaveDir

Tags: security, phpmyadmin

Regarding UploadDir & SaveDir in phpmyadmin, I have them both set to './save' with permissions at 755.

I am the only one using phpmyadmin, but still, **could I make this tighter**?

Thanks

```
PHP 5.3.3 via FCGId
phpmyadmin 3.5.1
Centos 6.3 (Linux 2.6.32.59-28)
```